# delimiter in C without built-in string functions

Tags: c

in today task i had to implement the function "my_split" that is based on pointers and accessing addresses, I'm having a little bit of trouble with "catching" all of the content from the file into the output.

this is my function:

```
void my_split(const char *source, char *first, char *second, const char delim){
    int ree = 1;
    while(*source != '\n'){
        if(*source == delim){
            ree = 0;
            *source++;
        }
        else{
            if(ree == 1){
                *first++ = *source++;
            }
            else {
                *second++ = *source++;
            }
        }
    }
    *first = '\0';
    *second = '\0';
}
```

Main function:

```
int main(void){
  int max_n = 200;
  char source[max_n];
  char strA[max_n];
  char strB[max_n];
  int T;
  scanf("%d%*c", &T);
  for(int i  = 0; i < T; i++){
    fgets (source, max_n, stdin);
    my_split(source, strA, strB, ';');
    printf("First: %s\n", strA);
    printf("Second: %s\n", strB);
  }
  
}
```

^^^ teacher gave us this one.

TXT FILE:

```
2
2345.454;6737.98
this is the line;splitted by semicolon
```

My output is:

```
First: 
Second:
First: 2345.454
Second: 6737.98
```

The desired output is:

```
First: 2345.454
Second: 6737.98
First: this is the line
Second: splitted by semicolon
```

I'm trying to make above function, but It didn't workout, well it works half-succesfull

Comment: Your code snippet lacks the input and output parts, making it difficult for people here to run your program and reproduce your problem. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include one.

Comment: Looks like you lack some basic understanding. For example, *source++; is equivalent to just source++;

Comment: True, @SvenNilsson, but it looks like `source++;` is in fact the behavior wanted at that point, and it is mostly harmless to get that via `*source++;`.

Comment: Very likely the issue is in the code you've withheld, not in what you've presented.

Comment: already pasted the main function from our teacher.

Comment: `while(*source != '\n')` invokes UB if line doesn't contain `'\n'` Should be `while(*source && *source != '\n')`

Comment: well, im still having problems, because those are not all the tests we  have to take into account, shouldn't I reset the source to the initial value after while?

Comment: Write a function void which splits up the text in the source array due to a delimiter that appears no more than once in the text. Copying is not to take place in the absence of a delimiter. The text for the delimiter goes to first, the rest goes to second.

Comment: My function should return empty array if there is no delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Your function seem to work. Try it like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_split(const char *, char *, char *, const char);

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == fp) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
        return 0;
    }
 
    char source[100];
    while (fgets(source, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        char first[100] = "", second[100] = "";
        my_split(source, first, second, ';');
        printf("First:  %s\n", first);
        printf("Second: %s\n", second);
    }
     
    // Closing the file
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void my_split(const char *source, char *first, char *second, const char delim){
    int ree = 1;
    while(*source != '\n'){
        if(*source == delim){
            ree = 0;
            *source++;
        }
        else{
            if(ree == 1){
                *first++ = *source++;
            }
            else {
                *second++ = *source++;
            }
        }
    }
    *first = '\0';
    *second = '\0';
}
```

It outputs:

```
First:  2
Second:
First:  2345.454
Second: 6737.98
First:  this is the line
Second: splitted by semicolon
```

Comment: oh so sorry, I've just pasted the main function from my teacher. Sorry for u all for waiting such time for this. EDIT: when im testing it now, this is the output: First: 2345.454
Second: 6737.98
Segmentation fault

@Anthony Kelly

Comment: Make sure you have a `\n` on the last record. Your function depends on it.